# unable to execute VBoxManage command in python executable (created with pyinstaller)

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, python3, exec

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

make an install.py file executable:

```
pyinstaller -w install.py --onefile
```

install.py script:

```
import os
VM = os.system('VBoxManage startvm win10 --type headless')
if VM == 0:
   print("win10 started...")
else:
   print("win10 not started....")
```

**Problem:** When I run the `python3 install.py` on ubuntu terminal it works fine. After that I created it's an executable file with the command mentioned above and when I execute the executable file on the terminal by giving command `chmod 777 install & ./install`. It gives an error below:

**Error:**

```
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED (0x80040154) - Class not registered (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or failed to start.
```

I don't know what's going wrong python script works fine but when I created it's executable it gives same error every time.

**Thanks in advance.**